# How to install latest unstable AngularJS components using Bower?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, bower

I’ve scaffold an AngularJS app using Yeoman:

> yo angular –minsafe

When I run “bower list” command I get following:

```
angular#1.0.8 (latest is 1.2.0-rc.2)
angular-mocks#1.0.8 (latest is 1.2.0-rc.2)
 -angular#1.0.8 (latest is 1.2.0-rc.2)
angular-scenario#1.0.8 (latest is 1.2.0-rc.2)
 -angular#1.0.8 (latest is 1.2.0-rc.2)
angular-scenario#1.0.8 (latest is 1.2.0-rc.2)
 -angular#1.0.8 (latest is 1.2.0-rc.2)
es5-shim#2.0.12(latest is 2.1.0)
json3#3.2.5
```

I would like to install the latest unstable versions of angular and it’s dependencies.

My bower version is 1.2.6.

What I tried to do was replacing the versions of components in bower.json:

```
{
 "name": "testapp",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "dependencies": {
   "angular": "1.2.0.-rc.2",
   "json3": "~3.2.4",
   "es5-shim": "~2.0.8"
 },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.2.0.-rc.2",
    "angular-scenario": "1.2.0.-rc.2"
  }
}
```

And running the following command:

> bower update angular –force-latest

That gave me the following error:

> bower ENORESTARGET Tag/branch 1.2.0.-rc.2 does not exist

Also I’ve tried to delete the bower_components folder, cleaning the cache using “bower cache clean” and then “bower install”. 
But I got the same ENORESTARGET error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: or you could just do "angular": "1.2.x", it will update(if available) to latest 1.2.x when you do bower update

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have error in angular version. It should be `1.2.0-rc.2` instead of `1.2.0.-rc.2` (see the extra dot after 0?)

`bower install angular#1.2.0-rc.2`

Comment: That's right. The packages have been installed successfully once I removed the dot after 0 and called **bower install angular#1.2.0-rc.2**. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any ideas where I can get the remaining components? The angular#1.2.0-rc2 installation does not include angular-resource and angular-mobile rc2.0

Comment: It's actually `1.2.0-rc.2`, with a dot between rc and 2

Comment: When I try bower install angular#1.2.14 I get a list of hashes and not the desired result.

Comment: @landed it is because there is no such version in their bower repo. You'll have to select one of the versions with 1.2.14 prefix (`1.2.14-build.2326+sha.332e935` for example). Link angular bower repo : https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/releases

Comment: I seem to have to manually do all of them like this and now some are again reverting back to an earlier build ! So I am submitting a ticket on their project. But thanks.