# How to upgrade to the latest Angular 1.3 beta version using Bower?

Tags: angularjs, upgrade, bower

I'm a little confused how to keep my application updated to the latest beta build of AngularJS using bower.  I'm currently using Angular 1.2.21 in my application.

bower.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.11.1",
    "underscore": "~1.6.0",
    "angular": "~1.2.21",
    "angular-route": "~1.2.21",
    "angular-resource": "~1.2.21",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.2.21",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.2.21",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.21",
    "angular-moment": "~0.8.0",
    "moment": "2.7.0",
    "angular-xeditable": "~0.1.8",
    "font-awesome": "~4.1.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "~0.2.4",
    "blueimp-file-upload": "~9.7.0",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "v3.2.0+1",
    "angular-deferred-bootstrap": "~0.1.3",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
    "moment-timezone": "~0.2.1"
  },
```

From other [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18846786/827480), I realize I can do:

```
bower install angular#1.3.0-beta.18
```

which will install the latest angular.  But how do I ensure that I always have the most recent?  If I specify `~1.3.0-beta.18`, bower will pick up every build as well, and not just the beta releases when I do a `bower update`.

Is there some way to specify that I only want the numbered beta releases and not the intermediate builds?  Similarly, I would want bower to update to the RC when they are released, and the full 1.3.0 release when it comes out.

How do I upgrade angular to the 1.3.0 beta release as well as all of the packages dependent on it?

Comment: May be something like `bower install "angular#>=1.3.0-beta.0 <1.3.0-beta.- || 1.3.0"`.

Answer (score 1):

`angular: "~1.3.0"` should give you the latest, including the latest build.

`angular: "~1.3.0-beta"` for the latest beta release

**BUG ALERT**: Tho I would suggest being very specific when using beta versions, we had problems when using CI deployment and the new beta had some changes we didn't account for.

Comment: The problem with `~1.3.0` is that it will upgrade to each build between beta releases as well. Not just Beta 17, Beta 18, Beta 19, etc, but also any Build.XXXXX

Comment: `"angular": "~1.4.0-beta"` has bower downloading 'build' builds and not just 'beta' builds for me on bower 1.3.12.